# EntityDateSource must implement IQueryableDataSource?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, search

I'm trying to use a QueryExtender control in ASP.NET to provide search on a GridView. I'm using an EntityDataSource, but when I wire everything up and run the code I get an error that:

> DataSource 'EntityDateSource1' must implement IQueryableDataSource.

How do I "implement" IQueryableDataSource? I'm running ASP.NET 4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/464001/queryextender-throws-exception-when-used-with-entitydatasource

It is a bug in the framework that was originally reported to MS while in Beta, but still exists in the latest version.

Comment: Thanks Shiraz. Funny enough, that is me on connect.microsoft.com reporting the issue is still in existence. :)

Answer (score 1):

The bug has been fixed in ASP.NET 4.  You can see QueryExtender used with EntityDataSource in this tutorial:
http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-–-getting-started-part-3

Comment: Unfortunately, I am already using ASP.NET 4 and am still encoutering this issue.